# How to control resource usage of my website?

Tags: 6

I'm using drupal 6 website and i don't know to check which module or script uses high resource. Below is the graph for my website Resource Usage from my hosting provider. They intimate me to control the usage. Really i don't know how i am going to solve this. And i am in shared hosting.

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: You have 3 options really - 1. throttle visits to your site. 2. Profile your site to find out what's wrong. 3. Move your site to a better server. We can't really help you with any of those here, it's too localised to your server and site setup. I won't close this or anything though, someone might have a better idea

Comment: I'd go for #2 on Clive's suggestions. Finding out how much resources your server has would be a good starting point and establishing whether it's suitable for you installation and requirements. I'd compile a list of modules that I have enabled and see if I can turn anything off. I'd try and look at caching options (if you haven't any). I'd also look at any custom modules that may be running on your installation, and skim through the code to see if it's written properly and has good logic. Also update your modules as that may improve performance (depends...). I don't know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by **upgrading to VPS** and also blocked the **unwanted bots** and limit the bot access.

Answer (score 2):

- Use the Devel module It should show you a list of queries run when
  the page is loaded and the time taken to run the query. From there
  you can check which query is coming from which module.
- You can also try a PHP profiler which gives you a lot of metrics.
- Or try disabling your modules one at a time to decide when the load
  time gets really high
- Another option lies in smarter caching

Comment: is it ok to use PHP profiler https://drupal.org/project/profiling  in production site