# Drupal feeds module causing high cpu usage when pulling feeds

Tags: 6, feeds, cron

I am using the Drupal Feeds module to download the feeds from an external site. I have setup a dedicated content type to pull the feeds and then created nodes of another content type for the individual feed items.

After updating the site recently I noticed that the site was using the CPU continuously so much so that the hosting tech support notified me about it.

I proceeded to limit the frequency with which the feeds were being pulled but the CPU usage remained constant and I was finally forced to disable cron.php.

This never happened before the update.

Checking the dblog I noticed that the JobScheduler initiated the feed pull (I had set the watchdog to print the title of each node being created) and was repeating this scenario every minute 24x7.

I have not figured out what is causing this issue or from where to start?

Any possible solutions guys?

Site runs on Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in shared hosting, then it is the right time to upgrade to VPS or Dedicated Server.

I had a same issue [How to control resource usage of my website?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76768/how-to-control-resource-usage-of-my-website/80171#80171) , better you can remove the unwanted bots. You need to see the **Access Log** in your hosting control panel.

try disabling your modules one at a time to decide when the load time gets really high and remove the unwanted modules and also it delete from modules folder.